# Как правильно развернуть Yii2 проект на хостинге?

Tags: php, yii2, .htaccess, apache, hosting

Как настроить домены правильно для backend и fronted? Cейчас на хостинге имеется 2 хостинг аккаунта-один работает с оплаченным доменом. На втором - этот сайт. т.е. к нему для backend нужно создавать субдомен?
Как правильно в таком случае развернуть проект? Читаю руководство Yii2 - и так понимаю, что нужно в корне сайта создать .htaccess(он сейчас пустой) и прописать там пути до фронтенда и бекэнда? А что именно прописывать нужно?
В настройках Open Server у меня было указано Apache-2-4-x64 PhP -5.6-x64 MsSQL -5.5

Сейчас .htaccess fronted/web выглядит так:

```html
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте!

Для "правильного" разворота Yii2 на хостинге необходимо задать webroot для основного домена frontend/web и webroot для поддомена backend/web

В каждую папку web необходимо поместить .htaccess с содержанием, что вы указали.

```
site.com - основной сайт (/frontend/web)
backend.site.com - администрирование (/backend/web)
```

[Установка Yii2 (basic&advanced) на виртуальном хостинге](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/tutorial-shared-hosting/)